# Updating all tables of DS rowstate to unchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, datatable, dataset

I have TypedDataset Files which contains 6 datatables. file01 to file06. I insert data into all those datatables so the rowstate of all table rows change to added. Now when i update  the datatable file01 like following

```
((System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter)da).Update(ds.Tables["File01"].Select("", "", DataViewRowState.Added));
```

it changes the rowstate of File01 and all tables (File02,File03, File04) which are dependent on table01 to unchanged instead of changing rowstate of only File01. 
**Note:**  **File01 has column Run_Cde which is foreign key in File02, File03, File04.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh that was so simple i just need to change Accept/Reject Rule to none instead of Cascade.. and that's all.